# Multithreaded application does not reach 100% of processor usage

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing

My multithreaded application take some files from the HD and then process the data in this files. I reuse the same instance of a class (dataProcessing)) to create threads (I just change the parameters of the calling method).

processingThread[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(dataProcessing.parseAll));

I am wondering if the cause could be all threads reading from the same memory.

It takes about half a minute to process each file. The files are quickly read since they are just 200 KB. After I process the files I write all the results in a single destination file. I dont think the problem is reading or writing to the disk. All the threads are working on the task, but for some reason the processor is not being fully used. I try adding more threads to see if I could reach 100% of processor usage, but it comes to a point where it slows down and decresease the processing usage instead of fully use it. Anyone do have an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: What about this process makes you think the bottlenecks are CPU?

Comment: Well, when I debugged the application, I see that all threads "are doing something". In fact, I gain some time using more threads, but if I add too many, performance decreases.

Comment: I think more information is needed. All of these tasks write back to the same file, so that could be the bottleneck. 30 seconds to process 200KB of data suggests something other than CPU bound processes...

Comment: No sir, I am running a complex algorithm on the information. Even if I don't write anything, it won't reach the 100% of processor usage.

Comment: You can only run as many simultanious threads as you have cores, so at some point additional threads will compete for time, reducing performance.

Comment: @roken yes I know this, but still why isn't my application reaching the 100% of processor usage? I have i7.

Comment: So how much CPU utilization do you actually get? If you're at 99%, then why worry about that 1%?

Comment: I hardly get to 70%, I did a improvement now it just takes 1 second to parse the files, but still not reaching 100% nor close.

Comment: Can you post some code? Preferrably, *all* code.

Answer (score 0):

Here some points you might want to consider:

1. most CPUs today are Hyper threaded. Even though the OS assumes that each hyper threaded core has 2 pipe lines this is not the case and very dependent on the CPU and the arithmetic operations you are performing. While on most CPUs there are 2 integer units on each pipe-line, there is only one FP so most FP operations are not gaining any befit from the hyper-threaded architecture.
2. Since the file is only 200k I can only assume that it is all copied to the cache so this is not a memory/disk issue.
3. Are you using external DLLs? some operations, like reading/saving JPEG files using native Bitmap class, are not parallel and you won't see any speed-up if you are doing multiple executions at once.
4. Performance decrease as you are reaching a point that switching between the threads costs more than the operation they are doing.
5. Are you only reading the data or are you also modifying it? If each thread also modify the data then there are many locks on the cache. It would be better for each thread to gather its own data in its own memory and combine all the data together only after all the threads have does their job.

Comment: The operations I am performing are not arithmetic operations. I made sure is not a disk bottleneck, since it takes less time for me to just open, read, and close the files. Yes, I am using external DLL, but I have multiple instances of HtmlAgilityPack HtmlDocument, one for each thread. However, they all share a data structure (just for reads).

Comment: I forgot to tag you in the previous message, any ideas?

Comment: Is there a point where the threads use locking, for example when reading the shared datastructure?

Comment: @Devela - I'll add my 2c to Gilad's answer - I would think that there is some locking going on between the threads or the same thread that is processing files is also reading/writing them (a read/write operation is a IO operation, very little CPU used during that time, which causes lower CPU utilization to show under taskmanager). What if you read all the files to memory first, then process the files, and finally write to disk. Do you see 100% CPU usage during the processing phase then?

Comment: Did that already, seems a XPath issue, not easy to parallelize.